# How to assign defective keys in Ubuntu Gnome?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keys

I'm new to Ubuntu. A friend who's a FOSS advocate influenced me to shift from Windows. Btw, I have defective letters **f**,**v** and **z** on my keyboard. I was able to assign keys **`**, **[** and **]** in windows to make those defective keys function but i can't figure out how to do it in gnome.

Answers will be appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to open keyboard in settings and go to shortcuts, then go to custom shortcuts, click the plus button and add the key that you wish to assign, then double click on it and it will ask you to assign a key, hope this helped my friend :)

Answer (score 0):

If my last response does not work go to terminal and type in
    xev 
a little window will come up, put the mouse in there and look for the keycode in terminal (youll see what i mean)

once you see the keycode go to terminal and type this in
e.g. 
    xmodmap -e 'keycode 67=b'